# Dont show mysql error in my app

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hello i have a level system in my app, that use 200 points to up a level, so when you have 0 points you cant up a lvl, I put "unsigned" in mysql to not allow negative values in my points column. But now, when user have 0 points and try to up a lvl show that message: [image]

Im usign this code to up a lvl, and deduct 200 points:

```
MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "server=xxxx;userid=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;database=xxxx"
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim query As String = "UPDATE EmployeeInfo Set nivel= nivel + 1,puntos = puntos - 200 WHERE user_name = ('" & My.Settings.user_name & "') AND password = ('" & My.Settings.user_password & "')"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

I just want to not show that error windows, and show a simple msgbox, without info about my mysql db. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate this situation with query logic: if you want to increase `nivel` when `puntos` is zero just ensure that no negative numbers are inserted for `puntos`:

```
puntos = GREATEST(puntos - 200, 0) ...
```

If you dont want to update anything when `puntos` is zero just add a clause to the end of the query:

```
AND puntos > 0
```